# Blank 'select all' button on SSRS parameter select display

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, displayobject

I have a program with multiple cascading parameters.  I’m puzzled why, if they’re all set up the same way (Available Values, Default Values, Refresh), they don’t display the same way.  In the images you can see that Job Type, Program Type, and Program Name all show the default ‘All selected’.  But Job Name is empty.  If I click on the down arrow, the values are all there and selected. (see second image).  Is there any way to fix this?

[image: initial parameter select display]
[image: correctly filled parameter choices]

Answer (score 1):

i think, in your Job Name collection.. there is some blank/empty record. the solution could be either you restrict those values or in parameter select option "Allow Blank Value"... 
All the best!

Comment: There were no emply records

Answer (score 1):

From memory this can happen if the query that populates the available or default parameter values includes a NULL in the result set.

Comment: No nulls in available or default parameters.  May have something to do with being driven by 'N/A' value - I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Because your dropdown list has so many label values in it, the concatenation of those labels is violating the maximum size allowable by that SSRS control. This is why the text "disappears" from the dropdown box when choosing (Select All). I have been unable to determine the exact character limit of this. If you want to spend some time confirming this, it's possible to begin with (Select All) and begin unchecking items until you see the text reappear in the box.

Because this limit is not configurable, one possible course of action to solve this would be to, on the query that populates that list of parameters, truncate those values down to a small number of characters so that when they're concatenated, that limit is not violated.

Comment: I've seen this happen many times in my reports.  No real solution besides limiting the list down.

Answer (score 0):

This could mean that you have Values set but do not have Labels set for the available values of the Job Name parameter.  Go to the parameter properties and select "Available Values".  If "Specify Values" is selected, then you need to enter Labels for each Value.  If "Get values from a query" is selected, then you just need to select a Label field from the drop down.

Comment: Available Values were set, same values as Default Values

Comment: There are two fields you can set for Available Values.  The Label and the Value.  Are both set to be identical to your Default Values?

Comment: Dataset: JobName - JobNameId,JobNameDesc;  Available Values: Dataset - JobName,Value-JobNameId,Label-JobNameDesc; Default Values: Dataset - JobName, Value - JobNameId